# An ellipse rolling inside a circle

Tags: conic-sections, cycloid

Is there a name to the curve created when you roll an ellipse inside a circle? Like for example, if it was a circle rolling inside a circle, the name of the curve could be prolate cycloid or curtate cycloid, depending on the position of the tracing point. So, is there a name to it?

Comment: Circle rolling inside/outside circle is called a hypocycloid/epicycloid. I don't think there's a general term for the locus of points you get rolling an arbitrary curve along an arbitrary curve, but you can certainly do it. :)

Comment: I think a generalization of the hypocycloid of a curve rolling against an arbitrary fixed curve is called a roulette. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette_(curve) An ellipse rolling on a line has a special name called an elliptic catenary, but I don't see a name for an ellipse rolling inside a circle.

Comment: [this site](http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/base/base.shtml) has the widest information about curves, and the section about Roulettes does not indicate the one  you mention.

Comment: Are you sure that the ellipse will always touch the circle in a unique point?

Comment: @BernardMassé Yea I am well aware that ellipse will not necessarily touch the circle. But let just say that it touches. So?

Comment: @user625 @G Cab  thanks!